# Close SqlAlchemy sessions automatically

Tags: sqlalchemy

With repository pattern I'd like to close SqlAlchemy sessions automatically (it could work in FastAPI):

```
def get_session():
    print("request for session")
    yield "session"
    print("close session")


class Repo:

    def __init__(self, session):
        self._session = session


class Handler:
    def __init__(self, repo1, repo2):
        self.repo1 = repo1
        self.repo2 = repo2

    def do_some_staff(self):
        pass
        

repo1 = Repo(next(get_session()))
repo2 = Repo(next(get_session()))

handler = Handler(repo1, repo2)
handler.do_some_staff()

# at the end all sessions inside all Repo instances should be closed
```

The code above does not work. Sessions are being close.

One way I could find is to close session manually like this:

```
def session_maker():
    return "session"


class Repo:

    def __init__(self, session):
        self._session = session


class Handler:
    def __init__(self, repo1, repo2):
        self.repo1 = repo1
        self.repo2 = repo2

    def do_some_staff(self):
        pass
    
    def close_all_session(self):
        self.repo1._session.close()
        self.repo2._session.close()
        

repo1 = Repo(session_maker())
repo2 = Repo(session_maker())

handler = Handler(repo1, repo2)
handler.do_some_staff()
handler.close_all_session()
```

But could them be closed automatically?